# How to use monotone convergence theorem to show that $\int \sum |f_n| = \sum \int |f_n|$

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, proof-verification, proof-writing

In https://math.la.asu.edu/~quigg/teach/courses/473/2009/lectures/11integral.pdf, pg 4

The monotone convergence theorem was used to state  $$\int \sum |f_n| = \sum \int |f_n|$$ without proof.

Can someone provide some instruction or reference as to how this result came about?

(Not very familiar with Lebesgue integration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\left|f_k\right|$$
and apply the monotone convergence theorem for $\left\{S_n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$.